# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs, backend, web-deployment, web-development-server

The header.ejs file contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Random Ejs testing
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

and the footer file contains:

```
           <p> Made By Shashank Singh </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to include these templates in my mammal.ejs file but am getting an error:
Mammal.ejs:

```
<%- include partials/header%>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<%- include partials/footer%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first one is that you have to use brackets and quotes for the filename. The fixes version of mammal.ejs should look like this:

```
<%- include('partials/header')%>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<%- include('partials/footer')%>
```

The other problem may exist is that the files that you include should also have an `.ejb` extension. So make sure you have named your files `partials/header.ejb` and `partials/footer.ejb`.

Hope this helps.

FYI I tried rendering with this code:

```
const ejs = require("ejs");

ejs.renderFile("mammal.ejs", null, {}, function(err, str){
    console.log("ERR", err);
    console.log("RESULT", str);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to following suggestion.It works for me & should work for you.

`
***<%- include('./partials/header.ejs');%>***

***<%- include('./partials/footer.ejs');%>***
`

Comment: maybe you can explain better not only say work for me & should work for you, you should not be lazy when answer